# Resuming interrupted s3 download with awscli

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli, resume-download

I was downloading a file using awscli:

```
$ aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/myfile myfile
```

But the download was interrupted (computer went to sleep). How can I continue the download? S3 supports the Range header, but `awscli s3 cp` doesn't let me specify it.

The file is not publicly accessible so I can't use curl to specify the header manually.

Comment: Isn't there anything like the wget --continue or rsync for aws s3? That is surprising

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a "hidden" command in the awscli tool which allows lower level access to S3: `s3api`.† It is less user friendly (no s3:// URLs and no progress bar) but it does support the range specifier on `get-object`:

```
   --range  (string) Downloads the specified range bytes of an object. For
   more   information   about   the   HTTP    range    header,    go    to
   http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35.
```

Here's how to continue the download:

```
$ size=$(stat -f%z myfile) # assumes OS X. Change for your OS
$ aws s3api get-object \
            --bucket mybucket \
            --key myfile \
            --range "bytes=$size-" \
            /dev/fd/3 3>>myfile
```

You can use [pv](https://github.com/icetee/pv) for a rudimentary progress bar:

```
$ aws s3api get-object \
            --bucket mybucket \
            --key myfile \
            --range "bytes=$size-" \
            /dev/fd/3 3>&1 >&2 | pv >> myfile
```

(The reason for this unnamed pipe rigmarole is that s3api writes a debug message to stdout at the end of the operation, polluting your file. This solution rebinds stdout to stderr and frees up the pipe for regular file contents through an alias. The version without `pv` could technically write to stderr (`/dev/fd/2` and `2>`), but if an error occurs s3api writes to stderr, which would then get appended to your file. Thus, it is safer to use a dedicated pipe there, as well.)

† In git speak, `s3` is porcelain, and `s3api` is plumbing.

Comment: Using `/dev/stdout` in this case is wrong as the command itself (`aws s3api get-object`) writes to `stdout`. One has to sacrifice the conveniency of `pv` and write simply:

`size=$(stat --printf="%s" myfile); aws s3api get-object --bucket mybucket --key myfile --range "bytes=$size-" myfile.part ; cat myfile.part >> myfile`

Comment: If I don't specify outfile, I get: `aws: error: the following arguments are required: outfile`. Version 1.16.30. "Cosmic rays, man" :)

Comment: Yes you do need to specify outfile -- it's `myfile.part` above. Apologies, I posted multiline code in one line, can't do it otherwise in comment apparently.

Comment: Ah, I get your point now! Sorry, my bad. Thanks for that, I'll edit the post :)

Comment: I've updated the command. Slightly adapted to work without temporary file, because this is subject is about large files and it lets us keep pv. Thanks for pointing out the bug!

Comment: @hraban I couldn't get `3>&1 >&2 >> myfile` to work (it printed the file to stdout), but I found that `/dev/fd/3 3>>myfile` worked well under OS X for me (file goes to myfile, stdout goes to screen)

Comment: @nonagon thanks for that! you're right, I don't know what I was thinking. that only works with the `pv` in between. I'll update. -- btw, be careful to `>&2` in your solution as well, otherwise you go back to the problem of adding noise to the tail of your file (as was originally flagged by @random )

Comment: @hraban no problem, I'm happy to help. This is such an important thing to be able to do, and your answer is the only place I was able to find it. Regarding `>&2` is that really necessary? I'm terrible at bash stuff but if it's writing to fd #3 and we're redirecting #3 to a file, does it matter whether stdout and stderr are writing to the screen? I tested my answer as it is (just `/dev/fd/3 3>>myfile`) and it seems to work without corrupting the file.

Comment: @nonagon fair point! if you just do it without `pv`, the `>&2` isn't actually necessary. That option has been in want of love because I never use it. But yes; you're definitely right. :)

Answer (score 12):

Use [`s3cmd`](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd) it has a `--continue` function built in. Example:

```
# Start a download
> s3cmd get s3://yourbucket/yourfile ./
download: 's3://yourbucket/yourfile' -> './yourfile' [1 of 1]
    123456789 of 987654321     12.5% in 235s   0.5 MB/s

[ctrl-c] interrupt

# Pick up where you left off
> s3cmd --continue get s3://yourbucket/yourfile ./
```

Note that S3 cmd is not multithreaded where `awscli` is multithreaded, e.g. `awscli` is faster. A **currently maintained fork** of `s3cmd`, called `s4cmd` appears to provide the multi-threaded capabilities while maintaining the usability features of `s3cmd`:

https://github.com/bloomreach/s4cmd

Comment: s4cmd (still) doesn’t support `—continue`

Comment: That's a great point Aleksandr, thanks for the comment. `s4cmd` doesn't have that feature. I failed to realize that when I last updated this question with the reference to `s4cmd`.